# Can't autoresize cell in table view with multiline label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to do a table view with a multiline label in it. Unfortunately, I had no luck with it - the cells don't seem to resize at all, although I get label to multiline.

My Swift code of TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class QuestionsController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questionsData.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuestionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BasicQuestionCell
        let question = questionsData[indexPath.row] as Question
        cell.titleLabel.text = question.content
        return cell
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result of my code]

Comment: What constraints are you using in this QuestionCell ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have not mention that if you are using auto layout or not, I'm assuming that you are using auto layout and have given necessary constraints to the label inside the cell.

Now just **remove** following two lines **from viewDidLoad()**:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And **add** the **default function** to pursue it as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   return tableView.rowHeight

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually, I've tried that solution before, but you made me realize that something must be wrong with my constraints - and that was the point. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can do to set the UICellView to match it's label's height. If you know the exact height you can simply implement:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return the height there
    return 100.0;
}
```

If you don't know the height, you need to get it's height at run time, and reuturn in the same function.

There are multiple ways of defining how your cells are structured. I am going to assume you're using dynamic prototypes and are simply using basic style cells.

In the above method you can do :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let hieght = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.frame.height {
            return hieght;
        } else {
            print("Couln't adjust the height")
            return 100.0;
        }
    }
```

If you're defining you cell's in different manner, you'd simply implement the same method, but return the height of your label within the cell.